# omnetpp does not start on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ide, windows-subsystem-for-linux, omnet++

I use Ubuntu-20.04 via wsl. There, I have installed ometpp-5.6. Also, on Windows, I have installed VcXserver to run onmetpp IDE. 
But when I run in the command prompt on Ubuntu `omnetpp` I get `Starting the OMNeT++ IDE...`, but no IDE window is being open, even though I have configured my environment as described [here](https://groups.google.com/g/omnetpp/c/QxiNwUqnvYc/m/qOJ5WrbOAQAJ).
How could I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Adding separate inbound rule for TCP port 6000 as described [here](https://github.com/cascadium/wsl-windows-toolbar-launcher#firewall-rules) solved the issue.

Comment: The title is a bit misleading as this question has nothing to do with ubuntu, but rather running OMNeT++ on Windows in WSL (no matter what is the underlying distro). As a side note, if you were on WIndows 11, WSL does support GUI apps in WSL out of the box, without the XServer requirement.